# jTextField loses focus on typing

Tags: java, jtextfield, focuslistener

I am trying to put a `lost focus` listener on a jTextField. However, the function is triggered when I am typing in the text field.

One possible way, in my opinion, is to start a timer when the focus is lost. However, I am not sure if this is the right way to go.

Any leads?

```
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
import java.awt.event.FocusListener;

import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        final JTextField textField = new JTextField();
        textField.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {

            @Override
            public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
                //Your code here
            }

            @Override
            public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Focus Lost");
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: Please add a [mcve] .

Comment: Better yet post a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/)